# Warm or cold air

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, everyday-life, water, humidity

Which air can be used to dry out food or clothes? Warm or cold air? I've read that keeping food in the fridge makes it dry out. Blowing hot air to the hair also dries the hair out. I'm confused.

Answer (score 1):

warm air that contains as little humidity as possible is best for drying out food and clothes. the reason why refrigerators tend to dry out unwrapped foods is the humidity inside a refrigerator is low, which tends to draw moisture out of food stored inside it. this process is slow because the temperature is low, which means that it takes a long time to completely dry out food in a refrigerator. To make it dry out fast, you need hot, dry air instead.

Comment: If the air is more humid and if I use hair dryer, will that help?

Comment: that will help, especially if the fan in the hair dryer is moving a lot of air.

Answer (score 0):

Both, lets assume that their is no moisture or moisture in dry and cold air is same. Since the thermal energy of warm air is more (proportional to temperature) there will be more energy transfer to those water molecules on that "thing".
Making it vibrate more (thermal agitation). 
The thermal energy just transfers its energy till equilibrium, in order to remove those water molecules from there place the wind is necessary which help to wipe them off.
Since temp > -273°C will cause thermal agitations and also there are some random fluctuations which cause will cause thermal agitation to those water molecules.
Thus, both cold and warm air can make things dry but not alone, some wind is required too.

Comment: air movement (wind) is not required, it merely speeds the process

Comment: Hey, I am wondering if there is no breeze or wind how can those water molecules get into the atmosphere?

Comment: water, above absolute zero, will give off vapor molecules at the surface. When close enough, gas molecules will repel each other, this is why it takes a force to compress gas.  As more evaporate they will push others away.

Answer (score 0):

Warm, dry air is best for drying clothes, because warm air can hold more moisture than cold air. This is why we often get rain wen a cold front sweeps in. When drying clothes, a breeze is useful, but not essential. On a sunny day with a light breeze. the sun will agitate the water molecules and cause them to jump out of the clothing, then the breeze will waft them away. As you say, cold air can also do the job, but not nearly so quickly or efficiently.